# 'Vagrant up' error - No file(s) found for import of 'nodes/**/*.pp'

Tags: vagrant, puppet, openam

I am new to OpenAM, vagrant, and puppet. I am trying to setup OpenAM following [OpenAM Vagrant](https://github.com/phinze/openam-vagrant) (& [here](https://libraries.io/github/zalando/openam-vagrant)). Using Oracle VirtualBox 5.1.8, Windows 7, and Vagrant 1.8.7 I tried:

1. git clone https://github.com/phinze/openam-vagrant.git
2. cd openam-vagrant
3. cp puppet/nodes/openam.pp.example vagrant up

The (error) trace:

> default: **Could not parse for environment production: No file(s) found
>   for import of** 'nodes/**/*.pp' at
>   /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests-768747907b90c39ab6f16fcb3320897a/site.pp:3
>   on node openam.vagrant.dev (*changed to my.dev.url*)

I have set a FQDN in `/etc/hosts` and updated the `Vagrantfile` and `openam.pp.example` file. I also looked at similar reported issues at SO, but was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 2):

did you rename the `/puppet/nodes/openam.pp.example` file to `/puppet/nodes/openam.pp` ?

once you do the update and run `vagrant up` :

```
==> default: notice: /Stage[main]/Timer_entropyd::Package/File[timer-entropyd-deb]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}cf94b08aac1f19e0b0681a5abf1964e1'
==> default: notice: /Stage[main]//Exec[apt-get-update]/returns: executed successfully
==> default: notice: /Stage[main]//Node[openam.vagrant.dev]/Package[vim-nox]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'present'
==> default: notice: /Stage[main]/Timer_entropyd::Package/Package[timer-entropyd]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'latest'
==> default: notice: /Stage[main]//Node[openam.vagrant.dev]/Package[curl]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'present'
==> default: notice: /Stage[main]/Tomcat::Package/Package[tomcat6]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'present'
==> default: notice: /Stage[main]/Tomcat::Config/File[/etc/default/tomcat6]/content: content changed '{md5}bc5b21625e2fa3cc8ada6ba03fe3bcd3' to '{md5}dbf709ff719e76ded1734582c6a1e2f1'
==> default: notice: /Stage[main]/Tomcat::Config/File[/etc/tomcat6/server.xml]/content: content changed '{md5}1733213f7f85c894ee210c14de6eddc1' to '{md5}0210005c49f6e01ada8dc27c3b712709'
==> default: notice: /Stage[main]/Tomcat::Config/File[/usr/share/tomcat6]/owner: owner changed 'root' to 'tomcat6'
==> default: notice: /Stage[main]/Tomcat::Config/File[/usr/share/tomcat6]/group: group changed 'root' to 'tomcat6'
==> default: notice: /Stage[main]/Openam::Prereqs/Package[unzip]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'present'
==> default: notice: /Stage[main]/Openam::Download/File[/usr/local/src/openam]/ensure: created
==> default: notice: /Stage[main]/Openam::Download/Exec[download-openam]/returns: executed successfully
==> default: notice: /Stage[main]/Openam::Download/Exec[unzip-openam]/returns: executed successfully
==> default: notice: /Stage[main]/Openam::War/Exec[install-openam-war]/returns: executed successfully
==> default: notice: /Stage[main]/Openam::Configurator/File[/var/lib/openam]/ensure: created
==> default: notice: /Stage[main]/Openam::Configurator/File[/var/lib/openam/configurator.jar]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}9c95981acd876be865a0293eb16eab89'
==> default: notice: /Stage[main]/Tomcat::Service/Service[tomcat6]: Triggered 'refresh' from 1 events
==> default: notice: /Stage[main]/Openam::Config/File[/etc/openam]/ensure: created
==> default: notice: /Stage[main]/Openam::Config/File[/etc/openam/initial_configuration.properties]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}b528e7c1773ae0bd5568657a90241b2a'
==> default: notice: /Stage[main]/Openam::Config/Exec[openam-configurator]/returns: Checking configuration directory /etc/openam/....Success.
....
```

Comment: Thank you, it proceeded till "ensure: defined content as..", then I got  {Could not start Service[tomcat6]: Execution of '/etc/init.d/tomcat6 start' returned 127:  at /tmp/vagrant-puppet}. Does it look familiar too?

Comment: well, is there something that was broken before ? honestly I did not run till the end. It sounds like the command is not found, is tomcat6 available under `/etc/init.d` ?